# Setup MirajeJS on NextTS 13 with the app directory

Tags: next.js13, miragejs

I would like to implement **MirageJS** on my **NextTS version 13** application (with the new app folder), but I can't find anyone who has already done this.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

```typescript
// layout.tsx
type import { Providers } from './redux/provider';
import './globals.css';
import { CustomGoogleProvider } from './google/provider';
import { Themelayout } from './components';
import { makeServer } from './mirage/mirage.config';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'App',
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  makeServer({ environment: "development" })
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <CustomGoogleProvider>
          <Providers>
            <Themelayout>{children}</Themelayout>
          </Providers>
        </CustomGoogleProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Mirage folder in my app:
[Mirage folder overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piaSp.png)